# the trait bound `&'a chain::Chain<'a>: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, serde

I'm very new to rust and I want to access a parent struct from a children.
I want to use `Chain` from its childs `Chain.blocks`.
So I'm trying to store a reference to the parent `Chain`.

But I'm encountering this error.

```
the trait bound `&'a chain::Chain<'a>: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
the following implementations were found:
  <chain::Chain<'a> as Deserialize<'de>>rustcE0277
```

This is my code.

```
// Chain
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Chain<'a> {
    pub blocks: Vec<Block<'a>>,
}

// Block
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Block<'a> {
    pub id: String,
    pub prev_hash: String,
    pub timestamp: u64,
    pub nonce: i32,
    pub proof: String,
    pub miner: String,
    pub documents: Vec<String>,
    pub merkel_root: String,
    chain: &'a Chain<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Default for Block<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I reply too late.

Comment: Serde can't `deserialize` to a struct reference. Where would it store the data the reference refers to? Try using `Box<Chain>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems

What you're trying to make is a self-referential structure, which is troublesome in Rust. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) answers, for example. It's not necessarily impossible, but it would be best if you try to find a different model for your data.

Also: `serde`'s derive mechanism doesn't care whether your field is `pub` or not, it will deserialize to it anyway. And it has no way to know that you want `chain` to contain a reference to its parent. In fact, it will generate a deserializer for block which can be used stand-alone. If you do wat @PitaJ suggests (`chain: Box<Chain>`), you'll get a deserializer that expects data like

```json
{
  "id": "foo",
  …
  "merkel_root": "You're thinking of Merkle, Merkel is the German chancellor a. D.",
  "chain": {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "id": "bar",
        …
        "chain": {
          "blocks": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Lastly:

```
impl<'a> Default for Block<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

is infinite recursion. But rustc would have warned you about this if you'd managed to get past the compiler errors.

```
warning: function cannot return without recursing
  --> src/lib.rs:25:5
   |
25 |     fn default() -> Self {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot return without recursing
26 |         Self {
27 |             ..Default::default()
   |               ------------------ recursive call site
   |
```

### If you absolutely want this

… against better advice, then you can get something close with reference counting (and my [favourite serde trick](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from)):

First, you need to solve the problem that serde won't know what to store in `chain` in `Block`. You could make it an `Option` and mark it `#[serde(skip)]`, but I prefer having a second struct with only the fields you actually want to be deserialized:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct ChainSerde {
    pub blocks: Vec<BlockSerde>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct BlockSerde {
    pub id: String,
    // … - doesn't contain chain
}
```

The actual struct you want to work with then looks like this

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "ChainSerde")]
pub struct Chain {
    pub blocks: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Block>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Block {
    pub id: String,
    // …
    #[serde(skip)] // Serialization would crash without
    // If you wanted Chain instead of Vec<Block>, you'd need another
    // #[serde(transparent, from = "ChainSerde")]
    // struct ChainParent(Rc<RefCell<Chain>>)
    chain: Weak<RefCell<Vec<Block>>>,
}
```

Now, all you need to do is to tell serde how to turn the deserialized struct into the struct you actually want to work with.

```
impl From<ChainSerde> for Chain {
    fn from(t: ChainSerde) -> Self {
        let b: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Block>>> = Default::default();
        let bc: Vec<Block> = t
            .blocks
            .into_iter()
            .map(|block| Block {
                id: block.id,
                chain: Rc::downgrade(&b),
            })
            .collect::<Vec<Block>>();
        *RefCell::borrow_mut(&b) = bc;
        Chain { blocks: b }
    }
}
```

If you want to wait for Rust 1.60, you can do it a bit more neatly and without the `RefCell` by using `Rc::new_cyclic`:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "ChainSerde")]
pub struct ChainNightly {
    pub blocks: Rc<Vec<BlockNightly>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BlockNightly {
    pub id: String,
    // …
    chain: Weak<Vec<BlockNightly>>,
}

impl From<ChainSerde> for ChainNightly {
    fn from(t: ChainSerde) -> Self {
        ChainNightly {
            blocks: Rc::new_cyclic(|blocks| {
                t.blocks
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|block| BlockNightly {
                        id: block.id,
                        chain: blocks.clone(),
                    })
                    .collect()
            }),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4dab7cbccb82fb065df0f5a52d4f2d2c)

Comment: Never seen a such a nice answer. Thanks. Will figure out what to do later on.