# How to serialize a state that contains internal references?

Tags: rust, serde

Suppose I have a `Zoo` consisting of `Animal`s, where `Animal`s need to have a reference to their `Species`. (`Species` can't just be an owned value underneath `Animal`, because it contains mutable data like population numbers, etc.) There are a few ways I can represent this. Off the top of my head:

1. `Animal` can hold a reference to to `Species` with a lifetime
   parameter on `Animal`
2. `Animal` can hold an `Arc<Species>` to avoid putting lifetime
   parameters everywhere
3. `Animal` can hold a `SpeciesID` (likely just wrapping a `usize`), and just keep a `Map<SpeciesID, Species>` elsewhere (basically implement my own reference to avoid the borrow checker altogether.)

I want to use serde to save/load the state of my `Zoo`. AFAIK, this is impossible except by option #3 above, as from [How do I use Serde to deserialize structs with references from a reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801133/how-do-i-use-serde-to-deserialize-structs-with-references-from-a-reader) it sounds like I can't serialize/de-serialize references at all.

This feels like I'm making a mistake, though: I'm basically re-inventing the wheel to avoid the borrow checker, by implementing my own clunky references through `SpeciesID`. It also requires that the set of `Species` be passed as a parameter to any operation on `Animal` that has to access `Species`, which wouldn't be the case for options 1 or 2.

As an added complication, I plan to have multi threading involved in this mess eventually, so `Mutex`s may be a thing at some level.

I could also see having alternate forms for serialization vs. runtime, with some translation step to convert rust references to and from the `SpeciesID` model around serialization. That sounds like a lot of error prone boiler plate, though.

Is there a better approach to this that I'm missing?

Comment: Serde can definitely serialize references, but not deduplicate them. Deserialization is more involved, though.

Comment: Using some kind of mapping between serde representation and the reference representation is how I would implement this (if I wouldn't go the `Map` route). There are multiple ways to implement that, though.

Comment: Question with a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619596/the-trait-bound-a-chainchaina-deserialize-is-not-satisfied/71625754) (but not a duplicate) with an answer ultimately going for the translation step approach.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can you elaborate on what serializing/deserializing with references would even look like? I mean, my understanding is you can't even make a struct which contains both values and references to those values - so are you serializing references to something from outside the serialized value, or...?